# Designing a Data Structure that allows both insertion and extracting a number lower than median in amoritzed O(1) cost?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, amortized-analysis

Consider a data structure that has only two functions. extract_lowerthan_median() and insert(). How can we design it in a way that the amortized cost for both the operation is O(1)?

Using a 2 tree, a min heap and max heap will ensure that the root of min heap is always the median and allow us to extract an element smaller than median with O(1) cost. However, the insertion would run in O(logn). Since we could amortize these cost there should be a structure which performs both these operations in O(1) where we somehow mask the cost of insertion in extraction but I cant think of anything

Comment: Hint: use Partition function from the Quicksort algorithm. In particular, take a look at CLRS, 3ed, Section 9 "Medians and Order Statistics".

Comment: @Dmitry I dont understand? The quickselect derivative of the quick sort uses randomized  pivot selection to find the median in average case O(n) but in my query I want to design a data structure with O(1) insertion and finding element smaller than median?

Comment: Yes. The keyword is "amortized". Another Hint: think about how the `ArrayList` gets $O(1)$ amortized time (although some changes are required here).

Comment: Another hint: the [medians of medians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians) algorithm finds the exact median in $O(n)$. It can be modified to find the $k$-th smallest element in $O(n)$.

Comment: Can you clarify, what exactly does `extract_lowerthan_median` means? Is it allowed to extract an arbitrary element less than the median? I was thinking, wouldn't it break the lower bound for comparison based sorting if we have $O(1) $ amortized for the two operations? Since the `extract_lowerthan_median` can be implemented for it to remove and return the current min element, which is less than the median.

Comment: @Russel yes an arbitrary element smaller than median. It shouldnt break the comparison based sorting because we are not getting the minimum every time. But you could be right about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### Amassing many elements significantly lower than median at once

The basic idea is to maintain a list of small elements that are guaranteed to be lower than median. Also maintain a list of all other elements that may or may not be lower than median, which will accept all new elements.

`extract_lowerthan_median` pops an element from the list of small elements most of the time. `insert` appends a new element to the list of other elements most of the time.

When there is no "small elements" or there are too many "other elements", the two lists will be adjusted so that the list of small elements will contain the $\lfloor n/4\rfloor$ smallest elements of all current elements, which can be selected using $O(n)$ operations. The very low frequency of this adjustment ensures the amortized cost of both `extract_lowerthan_median` and `insert` be $O(1)$.

##### The data structure in detail

For simplicity, assume no two numbers are equal.

Assume the median means the middle number when $n$ is odd or the mean of the middle two numbers when $n$ is even. "A number lower (smaller) than median" means any number that is smaller than the median. With the assumption of no equal numbers, a number among the given numbers lower than median also means a number such that the number of numbers larger than it is not smaller than the number of numbers not larger than it.

Build a data structure $D$ with two disjoint (unsorted) lists and a number,

- `small_nums`, a list of small numbers, which is empty initially,
- `other_nums`, a list of numbers, which is empty initially,
- `capacity`, a natural number, which is $0$ initially,

with three functions:

- `extract_lowerthan_median()`:

  1. If `small_nums` is empty,

     1. If `len(other_nums) < 8`, return accordingly. That means, if the smallest element is lower than median, pop it from `other_nums` and return it. Otherwise, return none. (`len(a_collection)` is the number of elements in `a_collection`.)
     2. Else, call `amass_small_numbers()`
  2. Pop an element from `small_nums` and return it.
- `insert(new_num)`:

  1. Append `new_num` to `other_nums`.
  2. If `len(other_nums) > 5 * capacity`, call `amass_small_numbers()`. This step ensures any element poped from `small_nums` will be lower than median.
- `amass_small_numbers()`:

  1. Move all numbers in `small_nums` into `other_nums`.
  2. set `capacity` to `len(other_nums)//4`. (`//` is the integer division such as `7//3=2`). Note that `capacity` is guaranteed to $\ge2$.
  3. Find the (`capacity + 1`)-th smallest element in `other_nums`, using a **linear-time $k$-th-smallest-element selection algorithm** as explained [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/kth-smallestlargest-element-unsorted-array-set-3-worst-case-linear-time/) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians#Algorithm). Denote it by `p`.
  4. Move all `capacity` elements in `other_nums` that are smaller than `p` to `small_nums`.

##### Some minor variations.

- greybeard suggested that `insert(new_num)` at step 1 add `new_num` to `small_nums` instead of `other_nums` if `new_num < p`, where `p` is the pivot computed in the last call to `amass_small_numbers`.  (If not, add to `other_nums` as before.)

  To implement this variation, the data structure should have one additional variable to store that pivot `p` and another additional variable `pop_count` to store the number of calls to `extract_lowerthan_median` since last call to `amass_small_numbers`. The condition `len(other_nums) > 5 * capacity` at the step 2 of `insert(new_num)` should then be replaced by `len(other_nums) >= 8 and (len(small_nums) + len(other_nums) + pop_count > 6 * capacity or len(small_nums) == 0)`.

  This variation may boost the performance, especially when there are lots of `extract_lowerthan_median`.
- Dmitry presented [a simplified version](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/154631/91753).

  After amassing the $n/4$ smallest numbers, call `extract_lowerthan_median` and `insert()` at most $n/4$ times together. Neither `extract_lowerthan_median` nor `insert` calls `amass_small_numbers`.

Answer (score 1):

John's answer is probably correct, but I just want to present a simple version that demonstrates the idea (in particular, I ignore the cases when $n$ is small, when there are duplicates, or when $4$ doesn't divide $n$; you can figure them out):

```
Let A be the initial array
while true:
    n := A.length
    Small := n/4 smallest elements of A, in any order
    Others := the rest of the elements of A
    process the next n/4 queries:
        For insert queries: add the new element to Others
        For extract queries: extract any element from Small
    A := (arbitrary) concatenation of Small and Others
```

You can find `Small` and `Others` in $O(n)$ using QuickSelect.